# make this algorithm AES for file not string

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption

Hello I need AES algorithm for data files not string 
and don't know how to modify this code.....
I want `public static String encrypt` get pass and file route and replace the encrypted file with original file

```
public class AES {
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    public static void setKey(String myKey)
    {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

1. `setKey` is `public`, but you use it as `private`. Don't set they key in `encrypt`, leaving it to the caller (my preferred option) or make it `private`, rebreanding it as some kind of helper function.
2. `encrypt` gets a `String` only to turn it into a `byte[]` (using `getBytes()`), and anyway you want to encrypt files, which are generally referred to as bytes, not strings (not all files are textual). It should get and return `byte[]`, IMO. If you want to treat the file as textual, ignore this one.
3. You want `encrypt` to do something it shouldn't. As named, it should only encrypt. Don't make it use files, etc.

So my suggestion is, create a new method `encryptFile`.
Use `Files.readAllBytes` (or read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java) about reading text files).
Use `encrypt` to encrypt the data.
Use `Files.write` to write back to file.

Comment: first a lot thanks for your help
you mean "public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] strToEncrypt.getBytes(), String secret)"  ?
so what about this line : "return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));" ?

Comment: No. `public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] toEncrypt, String secret)`. As for the return statement, you should just `.encode` (not `encodeToString`) and you shouldn't use `getBytes` as you have them already.